# Why interpolation repetition in table doesn't work for a symfony form?

Tags: php, html, twig, symfony4

I am trying to build a table in TWIG that would have a FORM in every header. When I interpolate a simple string variable like $smth="SOMETHING", there's no problem at all and I have a SOMETHING in every header. 
While when I try to build a FORM ({{ form(formTest) }}) right at the same place(!) - twig displays me the form only ONCE, in the first cell (together with SOMETHING). Seems not logic for me, does anyone have an advice on that? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
            <tr>

                <th>{{ form(formTest) }} dropdown menu {{ smth }}</th>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behaviour. The `form` widget actually "consumes" the `FormView` so you are not able to render it more than once.

Depending on your needs, you may want to render the form via HTML (you will still be able to use Symfony Form component in backend handling) or you may want to create a separate Symfony Form for each header.